# Implicit casting of a derived pointer to a reference of its corresponding base

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function that looks like:

```
// this function might modify base_ptr
void SomeFunction(shared_ptr<Base> &base_ptr)
{ if(some_condition) { base_ptr = some_other_ptr; } }
```

I'd like to call the function with a shared_ptr:

```
shared_ptr<Derived> d = ...;
SomeFunction(d);
```

This doesn't work though. It doesn't work if I'm using normal pointers either (ie. implicit casting to Base* & from Derived*. One workaround is to create a Base pointer from the Derived one, and then pass that to the function.

```
shared_ptr<Base> base = d;
SomeFunction(b);
```

But this isn't very pretty from a coding standpoint. It also adds confusion and the potential for a subtle bug:

```
shared_ptr<Derived> d = derived;
shared_ptr<Base> b = derived;
SomeFunction(b);
// b and d might now be pointing to different things -- not good!
```

Is there better way to do this?

Comment: do you really need to pass a reference to a shared_ptr?

Comment: you can just pass the pointer if you don't free it inside the function. Perhaps with a const qualifier

Comment: SomeFunction may explicitly modify base_ptr by changing what its pointing to. So the body of SomeFunction may look like { base_ptr = nullptr; } or { base_ptr = some_other_ptr; }. That's why I'm sending it as a reference in the first place and not a const& or just by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could template the function for the smart pointer's type

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:

    virtual void hello() {
        cout << "hello base" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:

    void hello() {
        cout << "hello derived" << endl;
    }
};

class otherClass {
    public:
};

template<typename T>
void SomeFunction(shared_ptr<T> &base_ptr)
{ 
    static_assert(is_base_of<Base, T>::value == true, "Wrong non-derived type");

    base_ptr->hello();

    // Rebase it
    base_ptr.reset(new Derived);

    base_ptr->hello();
}

int main() {

    shared_ptr<Base> obj(new Base());

    SomeFunction(obj);
    // hello base
    // hello derived

    shared_ptr<Derived> obj2(new Derived());
    // hello derived
    // hello derived

    SomeFunction(obj2);

    shared_ptr<otherClass> obj3(new otherClass());
    SomeFunction(obj3); // ASSERT

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/ATqhEZ

If you intend to update all the smart pointers when you reset one, you'll have to do some book-keeping by yourself since they're not designed to have a "signal-like" mechanism to notify other smart pointers pointing to the same object.

---

Edited my answer to provide compile-time safety if you intend to use it with Base and relative subclasses.

**Warning: the above solution uses C++11**, the same could be accomplished in a similar way in pre-C++11 code

Comment: Is there any way to restrict the template function to only work with types derived from Node?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is inherently dangerous, and C++ is making it hard on purpose.  Consider if C++ allowed you to call `SomeFunction` the way you wanted.  Then you could do this:

```
struct Base {
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
  void f1();
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
  void f2();
};

void SomeFunction(shared_ptr<Base> &p)
{
  p = make_shared<Derived2>(); // nothing wrong with converting 
                               // a Derived2 pointer to a Base pointer.
}

int main()
{
  shared_ptr<Derived1> d = make_shared<Derived1>();
  SomeFunction(d); // An error, but what if it wasn't?
  d->f1(); // Trying to call method f1 of a Derived2!
}
```

The compiler would not be able to know that `d` changed from a `Derived1` pointer to a `Derived2` pointer, so it wouldn't be able to give you a compile error when you tried to call method `f1` of a `Derived2`.

Comment: +1 I agree with this, I proposed the template mechanism since it somewhat offers protection from dangerous downcasts (or totally unrelated casts)

Comment: That's a good point. But one can argue that calling a function that takes a shared_ptr reference to some memory you own pretty much gives that function the ability to do whatever it wants to your memory. Reinterpret cast gives you free reign to do pretty much whatever you want too :)

Comment: @Pris: When you do a cast, you are telling the compiler that you know what you are doing, and that it should bypass its normal safety mechanisms.  If you happen to know that your parameter is still going to be a `Derived` pointer after `SomeFunction` returns, then why not just make `SomeFunction` take a `Derived` pointer?

Comment: @MarcoA.: That's true, but why not just make `SomeFunction` take a `Derived` pointer?

Comment: @VaughnCato I would totally agree with that, it's also a cleaner design. I'm just assuming there's a bigger picture involving memory management issues I'm not seeing right now (I really don't know)